# Google doesn't index my site-home page and google-search-console appear the message "Crawled - currently not indexed"

Tags: seo, google-search-console, search-engine-indexing, subdomain, angular

Hello it is the first time i am trying to deal with seo and i have a problem.
Almost a month ago google crawled my site but hasn't indexted it so yet. Google search console showed me only a short message "**Crawled - currently not indexed**" for the url of my site that is my home page. I have a small site written on Angular 2 with a few pages.

Note that is is a **subdomain** of the company's site for which I work and i don't know if it is a problem for google in order to index it.
So my questions are:

1. Why google doesn't index a small site after it has crawled?
2. Is there a possibility that the subdomain might be a problem for the first question?

Comment: We have many questions related to the [Crawled - currently not indexed](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7440203?hl=en) status [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=Crawled+-+currently+not+indexed+is%3Aq). As Google states, `It may or may not be indexed in the future`, however there's no way to tell. We generally mark these questions as a duplicate of the linked question since there are many factors that might impact whether a site is indexed or not. You might review the list there and see which could possibly apply to your site.

Comment: You might also review questions related to Angular and indexing [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=index+angular+is%3Aq). In regards to subdomains, Google can index them just fine, however you'll want to include your subdomain when using the [site: search operator](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/debug/search-operators/all-search-site) to see if it's indexed (i.e.., `site:subdomain.example.com`)